# Add and remove a class to an element based on the value of input in javascript (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to `+` and `-` button and one input. Input needs to start with zero. When i click `+`, number need to **increase by 3**, and when i click `-`, number need to **decrease by one**.

- If the value of input is negative, I want to print value with **red** color
- if value is > 10 I want to print value with **red** color
- if value is > 15 i want to print value with **blue** color.

Here is what I tried:

```
<div id="input_div">
<input type="text" size="25" value="1" id="count">
<input type="button" value="-" id="moins" onclick="minus()">
<input type="button" value="+" id="plus" onclick="plus()">
</div>

--------------------------------------------------------
var count = 1;
var countEl = document.getElementById("count");
function plus(){
    count++;
    countEl.value = count;
}
function minus(){
  if (count > 1) {
    count--;
    countEl.value = count;
  }  
}
```

My problems in code:
1. Start with 1(I want to start with 0)
2. When i press plus he add 3 (example: 1 click on plus value is 4) and then if I click plus he add just one (1 click on plus value is 2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add functions like this to add and remove classes based on the `count` value:

(Click on "Run code snippet" to test it out)

```js
var count = 0;
var countEl = document.getElementById("count");

function plus() {
  count += 3;
  countEl.value = count;
  calculateColor()
}

function minus() {
  count--;
  countEl.value = count;
  calculateColor()
}

function calculateColor() {
  removeClass(countEl, "red")
  removeClass(countEl, "blue")

  if (count < 0)
    addClass(countEl, "red");
  else if (count > 10 && count <= 15)
    addClass(countEl, "red")
  else if (count > 15)
    addClass(countEl, "blue")
}

function addClass(element, className) {
  element.classList.add(className);
}

function removeClass(element, className) {
  element.classList.remove(className);
}
```

```css
.red {
  background-color: red
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<div id="input_div">
  <input type="text" size="25" value="0" id="count">
  <input type="button" value="-" id="moins" onclick="minus()">
  <input type="button" value="+" id="plus" onclick="plus()">
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, when someone cant understand my quustion other guy solved it. Thank you so much, but wait, I need CSS for this?

Comment: Yes. I have just added 2 simple classes called `red` and `blue`. You can set the `background-color` attribute in javascript itself, but classes are much simpler and easier to add and maintain.

Comment: Okey but I'm so new in CSS, what I need to do so `.red {
  background-color: red
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue
}` work for me?

Comment: You need to add them in your `html` file inside a `<style>` tag. Like this: `<style> .red { background-color: red } .blue { background-color: blue } </style>` [More on style tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp)

Comment: Oh thank you, I thought I need to create new folder for CSS. Thank you so much, very good. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your initial count to 0 and change `count++` to `count += 3` like this:

```
var count = 0;
var countEl = document.getElementById("count");
function plus(){
    count += 3;
    countEl.value = count;
}
function minus(){
  if (count > 1) {
    count--;
    countEl.value = count;
  }  
}
```

And change value attribute of your input element to `0` too like this:

```
<input type="text" size="25" value="0" id="count">
```

Comment: This solve my problem with plus and minus, but not my value start. I already tried with inital count 0 but not working. Still show me 1 on start.

EDIT: Now work everything. Can you just help me a little bit how to start for my second problem?
 If the value of numbers is negative, i want to print value with red color, if value is more then 10 I want to print value with red color, and if value is more then 15 i want to print value with blue color.

Comment: @MarkoFilipovic You need to chang your HTML input value to `0` too. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Now wok fine, thanks. 

Can you help me with this problem:  If the value of numbers is negative, i want to print value with red color, if value is more then 10 I want to print value with red color, and if value is more then 15 i want to print value with blue color.

I dont know how to start

Comment: "If the value of numbers is negative, i want to print value with red color, if value is more then 10" Red for negative numbers or for 1- 10 or for 10 -15?? Please update your question and clarify that.

Comment: When i press plus and if value of number in that moment is higher then i want to print that value in dialog box in red color, if value after my click is higher then 15 i want to print that value in blue color, and If value after my click is negative I want to print value in dialog box in red color.

-1 red
10 + green
15 + blue

Comment: So what about 0 to 9?

Comment: Nothing, can be black .. I want to start to check value 
`if(value < 0){
....` but dont know how to print that in red color

Answer (score 0):

You need to put value as `0` in html

```
<input type="text" size="25" value="1" id="count">
                                   ^^^ change it to zero
```

Also you need to change `count = 0` and `count+=3'

```js
var count = 0;
var countEl = document.getElementById("count");
function plus(){
    count+=3;
    countEl.value = count;
}
function minus(){
  if (count > 1) {
    count--;
    countEl.value = count;
  }  
}
```

```html
<div id="input_div">
<input type="text" size="25" value="0" id="count">
<input type="button" value="-" id="moins" onclick="minus()">
<input type="button" value="+" id="plus" onclick="plus()">
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah that solve my problem with plus and minus, but program still start with 1.

Comment: @MarkoFilipovic did you changed value in html too ? Read in the answer explanantion

Comment: Yeah, now work fine. But can you help me with second problem I texted?
 If the value of numbers is negative, i want to print value with red color, if value is more then 10 I want to print value with red color, and if value is more then 15 i want to print value with blue color